# In shell pass results of "python -m SimpleSTTPServer" to pipe

Tags: python, bash, shell, simplehttpserver

I am trying to send the outputs of a Python CLI "SimpleHTTPServer" command to a pipe, in order to grep the results.  But it seems that the first line of the output is not being passed to the pipe, and I can't figure out why.

Here is the typical output from running the command.  The first line states that it has started a server, and the port it is using.  Then it reports various network activities as they occur.  So If I run `python -m SimpleHTTPRequest` and then load the index.html page twice, the output looks like this:

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2018 21:08:31] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2018 21:08:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

If I redirect `stderr` to `stdout`, and then send to a pipe, I would expect that all lines would arrive in the `stdin` after the pipe.  But this does not appear to be happening.  When I use `sed` after the pipe and have it prefix all lines with "This is stdin:", the first line of the output does not appear.

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 2>&1 | sed "s/.*/This is stdin\:&/"
This is stdin:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2018 23:35:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
This is stdin:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2018 23:35:11] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I tried different redirect options.  I can redirect `stdout` to `stderr` using `1>&2`, and this makes all three lines display without passing to the pipe, as expected.  I tried redirecting from `stdin` to `stdout` with `0>$1`, based on the discussion at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23118674/9756187), but that did not send any of the lines to the pipe.  I tried placing the python command in braces, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16497456/9756187), but it did not change the result.  It is clear that the network activity logs are being sent to to `stderr`, but it isn't clear where the first line is going.  I also tried with `grep` after the pipe, with the same result.  In all cases, the first line of the output is not arriving in the `stdin` after the pipe.

It appears that the python "SimpleHTTPServer" first line of output is not going to either `stdout` or `stderr`, so I can't pass it to a pipe.  What is happening?

---

In case someone has a better way around this, here is what I'm trying to do.  I want a one-line shell command that will (1) start a local server using python SimpleHTTPServer; (2) find out what port number it is using; then (3) open a browser at that localserver port.  I know that SimpleHTTPServer's default port is 8000; but if that one is already in use, it will assign a different one so I need to know that.  I also know that I can tell SimpleHTTPServer what port to use, but if that port is already in use then the command will fail.  I know that within python you can ask what port is being used, but I need a shell script to run from a different application.  So what I settled on was listening for the command's output when it starts the server, regexing the 4-digit port number, making that a variable, and then using that variable to open the right port in the browser.  I am expecting the following to work, but it isn't.

```
$ port=$(python -m SimpleHTTPServer 2>&1 | grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}') ; open http://localhost:$port
```

Comment: Does [my reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70618255/17850902) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm referring to Python3 and the module `http.server`, since Python2 reached its end of life. However, the same situation occurs there as well. The behaviour observed by you is related to the way, that this HTTP-server is realizing concurrency, while it is not flushing `stdout` before calling the cuntion `serve_forever()`, which handles the clients' requests (See [Lib/http/server.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/46c7a6566bca2e974a89c90c35ed1c498d9d3b02/Lib/http/server.py#L1247)). You could test this yourself by appending `, flush=True` to the function arguments in the call to `print` in line 1247 of [Lib/http/server.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/46c7a6566bca2e974a89c90c35ed1c498d9d3b02/Lib/http/server.py#L1247).

Since I assume, that you want to use Python3's HTTP-server anyways, you could use the following bash-script to achieve your task of spinning up an HTTP-server, finding its listening port and opening your system's default browser to open it:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Runs your server process
(python3 -m http.server &) >/dev/null 2>&1

# Adds delay, so that server started up
sleep 0.5

# Retrieves PID of the running server process
pid=$(pgrep -f "python3 -m http.server")

# Uses lsof to find the listening sockets
# -a is used to 'and' two filters
port=$(lsof -a -i -p $pid | grep -oP 'TCP.*:\K\d+')
echo "Server running on port ${port}"

# Opens the site
open "http://localhost:${port}"
```

Please note, that you would need to kill the server-process afterwards.

Hope, this helps!